# Почему не показывается результат в PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Всем привет. Только начал изучать Python онлайн и в задании спрашивают результат следующего примера:

[image: Screenshot]

Но в ответе у меня только одна надпись:

Process finished with exit code 0

Уже который раз так. В терминале Python вообще ни слова:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: На картинки нам смотреть неинтересно, если они не несут дополнительной информации, код должен быть текстом. А ничего не выводится, потому что 1) функция не вызывается, и 2) её результат не печатается с помощью print

Comment: в вашем коде просто описана функция, чтобы показать ее результат, нужно его напечатать, например так: `print(find_512())`

Comment: Почитать книжку по основам никогда не помешает.

Answer (score 2):

Когда вы запускаете код в PyCharm (тот же эффект будет и при `python foo.py`), то return возвращает результат, этот результат никто не получает и ничего с ним не делает, это раз. Когда вы пишите код в теле функции, то для того чтобы он начал выполняться требуется вызвать функцию, это два. В вашем методе есть условие, при выполнении которого будет возвращен объект str, если это условие не будет выполнено, то функция вернет None, это три.

```
def foo():  # объявление новой функции с именем foo, которая ничего не принимает
    return 1  # возврат значения из метода

result_of_foo = foo()  # вызов метода foo и запись результата в переменную result_of_foo
print(result_of_foo)  # вывод переменной result_of_foo в stdout (консоль обычно)
assert result_of_foo == 1


def foo():
    print(1) # вывод числа 1 в консоль

# в данном случае результат выполнения метода всегда будет None
result_of_foo = foo()
print(result_of_foo)
assert result_of_foo == None
```

Comment: Точно! я же не вызвал функцию! Спасибо

Comment: Поправка: при запуске данного кода до return дело не доходит, поэтому никакой результат не возвращается.